# UIPanGestureRecognizer with fadeout animation

Tags: ios, swift, uipangesturerecognizer

So i have an uiview inside my UIViewController. It looks something like this...
[image]

What i'm trying to do is, with an UIPanGestureRecognizer, that when i swipe to the right or to the left (starting at any green line in the image, and finishing in the other green line) the red view disappears, but with an animation of fadeout.

This is what i have tried...

```
let gestureRecognizer = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(gestureRecognizer:)))
    myview.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)

func handlePan(gestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
    
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.5, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseOut, animations: {
            //maybe this code works.??
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    
    if gestureRecognizer.state == .changed {
        let translation = gestureRecognizer.translation(in: self.view)
        //something with translation .x and .y values??
    }
}
```

But i'm not sure how to achieve my goal.
If you can help me... Thank you!!!

Comment: You aren't clear as to how UIPanGestureRecognizer comes into play.  You mean, you want to change the opacity level depending on the green line position?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't matter in which line you start, i want to change the opacity from 1.0 to 0. The distance between that 1.0 to 0 is the space between the green lines

Comment: do you want the view to move in the direction of the pan or just fade out with the pan?

Comment: when i swipe to the left (for example), i want the red view to be disappearing while i move my finger; from a green line to another green line